# Ordered tree in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a folder structure which I need to store in a database. Each folder has a name, a primary key and a foreign key to their parent folder. So a folder can have sub folders.

What I am having trouble with is when a user wants to move up or down or add a new sub folder (adding a sub folder is added at the end of the tree) and I want to record the order of the sub folders.

How do I record the user ordering in a table?

So if I have sub folders B, C and D under A (in that order) and I move D up, then the order is B, D and then C. How do you reflect this in a database?

Comment: Err, could you maybe give a graphical example of what you're attempting?  I'm not sure what final table structure you're attempting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to create a sub-hirarchy you can apply a order by clause with a integer to sort. for example

```
ID, ParentID, SortOrder, Name
```

Where `SortOrder` is a integer between 0 and foldercount-1 then just apply a

```
ORDER BY SortOrder ASC
```

I would also suggest you add a Lineage and Depth field to your table, that way you can easily traverse up and down the tree a bit quicker without as expensive queries. Have a look at [this article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql).

Comment: Thanks. If I move one entry up, I would have to update all the sort orders for each child below the moved entry? Also, what if I remove an entry, I would have the same issue, no?

Comment: You would, but this is easily combated by always inserting at the highest number already existing+1 remember order doesn't need to be contiguous, it could be 1 4 8

Comment: So if I want to swap two entries, I would basically swap the sort orders (other remain where they are). Is this correct? And if I want to add an entry, as it is at the bottom, I just increment by 1 the last sort order value and then insert the entry?

Comment: Thanks for the help. At the moment we don't need traversal up or down. From the parent we lazy load the children so we if required I could put in depth and lineage later.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative way to keep hierarchical structures in one table, called nested sets. This model allow faster queries for children or parent nodes by the price of alterning tree.

Consider table

```
id    left    right    node

0     0       9        root node
1     1       4        left node
2     5       8        right node
3     2       3        left sub node
```

.... etc

In order to get all parents of node N we need to find all records where (left-i; right-i) will include set (letf-N; right-N)

In order to get all children of node N you need to find all records where (left-i; right-i) are included in (left-N; right-N)

So nested set model allows to make simple hierarchical queries without recursion.

Here is [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) on Nested Set Model

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the `HierarchyID` data type?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you're looking for is [hierarchical queries](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2007/09/06/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2005---CTE-Example-of-a-simple.aspx). This enables you to automatically do a depth-first query on your hierarchical table, and define a sort order on any level of the hierarchy (so that each folder is ordered, but after each item you will get its sub-items before getting the next item on that folder).